# Parameters for fetch first rows in query

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, fetch, rowcount

I have the following query:

```
WITH lftno(counterrow) AS (
    VALUES(select rownos 
           from test.table1 
           where  year='2020' and usage='1')
)
UPDATE test.deltable
    SET year=concat('31.12.','2012')
WHERE ID IN (
    select res.id
    from (
        select res.id
        from (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY year ASC) AS delyear
                  , ID, year
            from test.deltable
        ) res
        where year(res.year)='2012' 
        fetch first integer(counterrow) rows only
    )
```

The result of the with select is 10 so I want the fetch first line to use that 10 as the value for the rows to catch.

The final query is a lot longer but to show the problem this is easy for readablity.

I tried

```
'fetch first ' || integer(counterrow)  || ' rows only'
```

or as part of the where clause

```
 AND row_number() over() <= counterrow
```

but that didn't work either.

The point is that I can not resort them with an over part. I just need the lines as given by the counterrow.

Any ideas?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: As a side-note the VALUES clause is un-necessary, you can replace `VALUES(select rownos 
           from test.table1 
           where  year='2020' and usage='1')` with `select rownos 
           from test.table1 
           where  year='2020' and usage='1'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `row_number()` in a `WHERE` clause.  And, the `FETCH` clause requires constants.  But, you can use the `row_number()` in a subquery and use the *result* in the outer query.  If I understand correctly, you want:

```
WITH lftno(counterrow) AS (
      VALUES(select rownos from test.table1 where year = '2020' and usage = '1')
     )
select res.id
from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY year ASC) AS delyear,  
             ID, year
      from test.deltable
     ) res
where year(res.year) = '2012' and
      delyear <= counterrow;
```

Comment: I added more info to the query in the question so you can see that this is not an option.

Comment: @Thevagabond . . . There is no such things as some given order for `lftno`.  SQL tables, subqueries, CTEs, and results sets all represent *unordered* sets.  Only a separate column specifies the ordering.